# How to add multivalue atribute to mysql workbench?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

How can i add multiple values to my table called 'courier'?

I need to add a second telephone number. The way i created table was:

```
create table kurier (
    id_kurier int not null,
    imie varchar(45) not null,
    nazwisko varchar(45) not null,
    telefon int not null,
    id_rejon int,
    nr_rej varchar(45) not null,
    id_przelozony int,
    constraint id_kurier primary key (id_kurier),
    constraint id_przelozony foreign key (id_przelozony)
    references kurier (id_kurier)
)
```

Comment: What do *you* mean by "multivalue attribute"?  Sample data and some explanation, please.

Comment: i think you have two option, json or a second table like kurier_telephone

Comment: Its NOT normally the best solution, but if you are Absolutely Positive you wont need a third phone number just add a `telefon2` column or maybe call it `mobile` if thats what it is.

Comment: I mean that 1 courier can have more than one telephone number and it has to be in same table. I found something about 'self joint' but it doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are various options, among them few are as follows:

1- (Discouraged) Add another column to hold telphone2. (but in case you are going to have more numbers then you need more columns)

2- (BEST) Create a child table that stores telephones numbers per courier (as a foregin key). This can hold as many as you need. Move your initial data into child table, drop column from original table.

3- (Alternative) Use a separator to store multiple data as string for eg. using comma (,) the data will look like `99999999, 8888888, 77777777`. You can then fetch and split values by the separator you chose for rendering and/or reporting purposes.

Hope this helps !